# Создание карты "символ-порядок добавления"

Tags: c++

Хочу создать `std::unordered_map<char, std::size_t>`, который для каждого добавляемого символа будет хранить номер, под которым он был добавлен (начиная с 0, добавляемые символы уникальны). Думаю написать

```
std::unordered_map<char, std::size_t> map;
for (auto character : characters)
   map[character]=map.size();
```

Не будет ли это `UB`? Есть ли способ лучше?

Comment: `map[character] = 0; map[character] = map.size() - 1`

Comment: И почему это должно быть UB ?

Comment: а  characters это что?

Answer (score 1):

```
void
creat_map( std::unordered_map<char, std::size_t>& map,
           const std::string& characters )
{
    static size_t index{};
    for (char ch : characters)
        map[ch] = index++;        
}
```

чтобы каждый раз не вызвать `map.size()`